# Fun with Flags part 4: a pile of coasters

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, flags

These quaint looking coasters appear to have been thrown haphazardly on the table.

However, there is a 10-letter word to be found, which is the answer to this puzzle.

[image]

---

<sub>Other (independently solvable) puzzles of this type: [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/fun-with-flags-part-1-something-different), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93603/fun-with-flags-part-2-a-musical-connection), [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93817/fun-with-flags-part-3-what-used-to-be), [5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94711/fun-with-flags-part-5-with-a-smile), [6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96773/fun-with-flags-part-6-left-right-left), [7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97350/fun-with-flags-part-7-attention-please), [8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97682/fun-with-flags-part-8-its-your-roll), [9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98072/fun-with-flags-part-9-a-different-design), [10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98671/fun-with-flags-part-10-dont-lose-count).</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@MichałWójcik made good inroads into this puzzle, and his answer proved helpful for my own (go upvote him). The 10-letter answer to this puzzle is:

> **ANTIPODALS**

Michał correctly identified 9 of the 10 flags; however, he needed to rotate the tenth one by 180 degrees to find the right country (had this been the only finding left to the puzzle I would have merely posted this as a comment on his answer; however, there is a little more afterwards...):

> Counting the occurrences of each kaleidoscopic country flag in the diagram, we find:
>
>  6 flags of Urugu[A]y
>  1 flag of [N]ew Zealand
>  1 flag of [T]aiwan
>  2 flags of F[I]ji
>  1 flag of [P]eru
>  2 flags of S[O]uth Korea
>  6 flags of Cambo[D]ia
>  2 flags of P[A]raguay
>  3 flags of **Ma[L]i** (not Guinea)
>  1 flag of [S]pain
>  [image]
>  If (as Michał did) you then index the letters of each country name using the number of times its flag appears in the image, and order them as in the list above, this results in spelling out the word **ANTIPODALS**.

What does this mean?

> Two places that are *antipodal* to each other are situated on exactly opposite locations of the globe - i.e. *on the other side of the world*. And this helps us notice something else special about this puzzle - namely, that the 10 countries used in the puzzle can be separated into 5 pairs of 'antipodals' (or 'antipodes'):
>
>  Cambodia & Peru
>  Fiji & Mali
>  New Zealand & Spain
>  Paraguay & Taiwan
>  South Korea & Uruguay
>
>  A useful website for checking these, and finding the antipodes of other locations is found at [geodatos.net](https://www.geodatos.net/en/antipodes). You can also visualise this well using Google Earth (antipodal pairings in the same colours - note the almost mirror-image effect of the labels across the 2 images):
>
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Well done and nice explanation

Answer (score 11):

Not sure, but the rule is probably:

> Count the occurrences of flags of individual countries - n and then get n-th letter of the name:
>
>
>   6x Uruguay -> A
>
>   6x Cambodia -> D
>
>   3x Guinea -> I
>
>   2x Paraguay -> A
>
>   2x South Korea -> O
>
>   2x Fiji -> I
>
>   1x Spain -> S
>
>   1x New Zealand -> N
>
>   1x Peru -> P
>
>   1x Taiwan -> T
>
>
>   Letters:
>
>   ADIAOISNPT

I also  noticed:

> Shape of circles is a little bit like the shape of Asia and in this list of ten letters there actually are 'ASIA' letters. But I can't find the 10-letter word...

The last idea:

> If instead of Taiwan there would be a country starting with "S" (Samoa is quite similar...), then the list of letter would be:
>
>
>   ADIAOISNPS
>
>
>   And their anagram:
>
>
>   ADIOS SPAIN
>
>
>   Which seems logical, because Spain is the only European country in this set.

Comment: Uruguay and Paraguay and Peru and Guinea and Fiji are also non-Asian, for what it’s worth....

Comment: I know :) treat them as two separate (possible) solutions/ideas - then it has nothing to do with Asia