# Fun with Flags part 5: with a smile

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, flags

We are looking for a song (artist and title).

[image]

---

<sub>Other (independently solvable) puzzles of this type: [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/fun-with-flags-part-1-something-different), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93603/fun-with-flags-part-2-a-musical-connection), [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93817/fun-with-flags-part-3-what-used-to-be), [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94515/fun-with-flags-part-4-a-pile-of-coasters), [6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96773/fun-with-flags-part-6-left-right-left), [7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97350/fun-with-flags-part-7-attention-please), [8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97682/fun-with-flags-part-8-its-your-roll), [9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98072/fun-with-flags-part-9-a-different-design), [10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98671/fun-with-flags-part-10-dont-lose-count).</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As figured out by both Lanny Strack and Rand al'Thor,

> The image depicts five flags (American Samoa, Bolivia, Guatemala, Mozambique and Sri Lanka), with different types of weapons removed.

Combined with the title, the song must be

> "Disarm" by The Smashing Pumpkins, which contains the line "disarm you with a smile".

Also, as noticed by Stiv,

> The Smashing Pumpkins' logo is drawn in the four corners of Sri Lanka's flag.

Comment: Well done, this is correct. By the way, I did include a hint for the band name in one of the flags...

Comment: Nice... Also rot13(Purpx bhg gur flzoby va gur pbearef bs gur qentba frpgvba bs gur Fev Ynaxn synt - vg'f n Fznfuvat Chzcxvaf ybtb...)

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> As all of the weapons are removed from the flags (of American Samoa, Bolivia, Guatemala, Mozambique, and Sri Lanka) ---  'Knives Out' by Radiohead.

**Revised**

> Another generic word meaning 'weapons' (of all types) more likely to be found in a song title is 'arms'. There are several songs which seem apt for the solution, including:
> 'Farewell to Arms', by Emerson, Lake, and Palmer
> 'Arms Out', by Curve
> 'Empty Arms', by Stevie Ray Vaughan
> 'Open Arms', by Journey

Comment: Wow, beat me by 7 seconds :-) Have a +1, but I'm not sure if your song answer is correct as they're not all knives. (Not that I've done any better on the song, of course!)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure, either. Also, my answer doesn't tie in to the puzzle title, either.

Comment: rot13("Qvfnez" ol Gur Fznfuvat Chzcxvaf npghnyyl pbagnvaf gur jbeqf "jvgu n fzvyr".)

Comment: @jafe: You've got the right answer. Go ahead and post it and get the credit. I'm OK with that.

Comment: @LannyStrack Alright, I posted a separate answer.

Answer (score 5):

These flags are for

> countries which have **weapons in their national flags**, but with the weapons removed.

Specifically,

> [American Samoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Samoa#/media/File:Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg) without the spear, [Bolivia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Bolivia_(state).svg) without the spears/guns, [Guatemala](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Guatemala.svg) without the gun, [Mozambique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Mozambique) without the gun, [Sri Lanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Sri_Lanka) without the sword.

So the song must be

> Something about "without weapons" or "without guns and spears"? (I don't know many modern songs.)

Answer (score 1):

Like Lanny Strack and Rand al'Thor already stated..

> They are flags(American Samoa, Bolivia, Guatemala, Mozambique and Sri Lanka) with the weapons removed.

So, based on that...

> I think the answer might be **The Beatles - Happiness is a warm gun**

More reasoning:

> You've written "with a smile" on the second part of the title, which makes me think of happiness. And also, to notice, these are all 'tropical' countries and this fits the *warm* part of the title of the song.