# Fun with Flags part 10: don't lose count

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual, flags

In a Formula 1 race, the chequered flag was waved so violently that the black and white patches got mixed up. Who was waving the flag, when and where?

[image]

---

<sub>Other (independently solvable) puzzles of this type: [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/fun-with-flags-part-1-something-different), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93603/fun-with-flags-part-2-a-musical-connection), [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93817/fun-with-flags-part-3-what-used-to-be), [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94515/fun-with-flags-part-4-a-pile-of-coasters), [5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94711/fun-with-flags-part-5-with-a-smile), [6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96773/fun-with-flags-part-6-left-right-left), [7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97350/fun-with-flags-part-7-attention-please), [8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97682/fun-with-flags-part-8-its-your-roll), [9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98072/fun-with-flags-part-9-a-different-design).</sub>

Comment: My gut says this looks like a rot13(onpba pvcure), but I can't get it to work in any orientation ...

Comment: I also tried rot13(kbe jvgu n purpxreobneq cnggrea naq gura frireny 5-ovg rapbqvatf, ohg V unira'g gevrq onpba pvcure); you may want to do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So this seems a little too easy, but I think the answer is:

> Winnie Harlow, 10 June 2018, Canadian Grand Prix in Montreal, Quebec, Canada

The reasoning:

> The columns of the flag are encoded with Baudot-Murray ITA2 code, and read "TWO MORE LAPS". The Canadian Grand Prix in 2018 was terminated two laps early when the race officials lost count of the number of laps.

Comment: You got the checkmark. Yeah I figured this puzzle would be easier than most of the other puzzles in this series. At least it didn't get solved within ten minutes from posting :)